# How can you deflect a direction/magnitude vector based on a direction/magnitude vector and a collided triangle?

Tags: c++, vector, graphics, 3d, geometry

So, I have a Triangle->AABB collision algorithm and I have it returning the triangle that the AABB collided with. I was hoping with the 3 vectors of the triangle and the direction/magnitude of the movement would let me determine a deflected vector so that when you run against the wall at an angle you move slower, depending on the angle of collision, but along side the wall. This would remove the sticky collision problem with only moving when there is not a collision. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the component of the velocity along the normal of the triangle.

The idea is that you can represent the movement as the part that's moving "into" the triangle and the remainder (which will be in perpendicular directions).  If you then just move with the remainder, you will no longer be getting any closer to the triangle by the movement (or further, but you shouldn't be detecting a collision in that case).

In pseudo-code:

```
// v := velocity vector of moving object
// p[3] := points that make up the triangle

triangle_normal = cross(p[2]-p[0], p[1]-p[0])
problematic_v = project(v, onto=triangle_normal)
safe_movement = v - problematic_movement
```

Note that this intentionally doesn't preserve the magnitude of the movement vector, as doing so would make you slide along a wall very quickly when running straight at it.

For more details and some nice pictures, see [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php) at Gamasutra.  You're not using spheres, but you are essentially doing a perfectly plastic (since you don't bounce) collision.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I follow you. Normalizing the triangles vector and then subtracting the direction/magnitude doesn't seem like it would do anything. Could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: The triangle and the vector of magnitude/direction are both in 3 dimensions.

Comment: It's probably not helping that "normal" and "normalized" are actually unrelated words.  I'll update.

Comment: I see, what you mean now :) Thanks very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would convert magnitude/direction to a vector (it's much more convenient).

Then (c++):

```
float towards=dot(velocity,norm);  // velocity component into triangle
if(towards<0)                      // is moving into triangle
  velocity-=towards*norm;          // remove component
```

Then it can't move into the triangle.  `towards<0` might need to be reversed depending on your normal.  It's also nice to have a spring force pushing it out.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, unfortunately neither of these solutions worked for me. I will have to keep searching I guess